# Browser "back" history list has multiple entries for the same pages in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, browser-compatibility, browsers

Our company uses SharePoint Online for our public-facing website.  All was well until a week ago.  When browsing our website, clicking through links, it was discovered one would sometimes have to click "back" several times to return to the previous page visited.  Clicking once would just refresh the page you are on.  When looking at the browser history, there were two or three entries for each page, so viewing the history list would look something like this:

- Careers
- Careers
- Careers
- Events
- News
- News

I'm not 100% sure when this happened but it is quite noticeable so I doubt it would have made it through our QA.  We did notice that SharePoint Online released a new build version last week, so we think it could be related.

The number of entries is quite random, from 1 to 10 or more, usually about 3 or 4.  It seems to be pages with custom apps that have extra entries (which is most of our pages), the ones that correctly only have one history entry have no custom apps on them.  This issue occurs in Chrome and Firefox.  In Internet Explorer 9 and 11, it also occurs, but the page titles in the history are either the IDs of the custom apps, or "Working on it...", text which only appears on the custom apps.

I've not found this issue documented online, so not sure what could be causing it.  We're not really sure what to try or to look for.  Any advice or tips to point us in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  **How can we ensure that only one entry for each page visited is entered into the browser history list?**

---

EDIT:  **@wjervis** Thanks for your comment.  It is on most pages.  The page doesn't reload or post back; this issue occurs just clicking through the page.  In the example above, clicking the "news" link on the home page, clicking the "events" link on the news page, clicking the "careers" link on the events page.

After a bit more investigation, I think the problem lies in the fact that the custom apps are displayed in iframes.  Perhaps SharePoint moved from providing the src of the app with document.location.assign(url) to document.location.replace(url).  Does SharePoint update the iframe URL with JavaScript?  Perhaps there is some way to override this SharePoint method?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.replace

Comment: What is on the page?  What are users doing?  If a user filters or sorts a list view web part on a page, it causes a postback; that would create an 'entry', as you call it.  If there's an app part, it too can cause a postback.  There are a variety of things that can cause your page to load again, creating these multiple 'entries'.

Comment: Ah, the apps are likely the cause.  I have an app on my home page (all it does is update a list with who is accessing the page, and what time), and after the page is done loading, if I look at the browser history, there are two entries for the page.

Comment: If you take a look at the entries you will probably see that the last one is appredirect.aspx, if that is the case then it is due to an app that lives in an iFrame.

Comment: Some of the entries contain the URL to the Azure website where our apps are hosted, so I'm convinced it is due to the apps.  So does this mean that all SharePoint pages that have apps (most of them?) break the browser history?  That seems like a very serious oversight...